# Is App considered to be a component in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Here is the explanation of the App.js:

```
App.js the first file in any React Native app that is the entry point of the app development process. Whatever you write inside this file, it will get displayed on the mobile device.
```

Is the App considered to be a component in React Native framework and has the life cycle as any other component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes same as react js just need to link your modules with android as well as ios if they need ,and also you can't use div span and other html attributes instead you can use react native ready made components

Comment: Somehow `App.js` is a little confusing to me. I have to write a SplashScreen component for async  retrieving initial data and can not call `async` function inside of  `App.js`. The `App.js` has some different behavior than normal RN component.

Comment: Why async function can not be implemented in `App.js`?

Comment: you can use using useEffect() hooks with function base component and compodidmount() with classbase component r., make function with async and call inside useEffect or componentdidmount